# Cartodb popup opening at wrong location

Tags: leaflet, carto, carto-js

i am using carto js to load a map and inbuilt leaflet to load additional points following (see image below) is the error i am getting.
[image]
i am using this js

```
<script src="http://libs.cartocdn.com/cartodb.js/v3/3.15/cartodb.js"></script>
```

my code is this

```
    var map;
    var sale_layer;
    //----------------- Declarations END ----------------------

    //XXXXX------- Page load Triggers --------------XXXXX
    window.onload = function (){
        //---------- Intialize ------------------
        triggers();
        initializemap();
        //loadmap();
        drawLayerControl();
    }
    //XXXXX------- Page load Triggers END ----------XXXXX

    //----------- Map Loading functions -----------------------
    function loadmap(){ //Map Loading Function
        //$("#mapCanvas").html("Loading....");
        //$("#mapCanvas").html("");

        var query = loadquery();
        if (!(query)){
            return
        }
        query = query.replace('where','and');
        loadbadges(query);
        //console.log(query);
        //SELECT now() AT TIME ZONE 'Asia/Calcutta';
        //extract(date from SELECT now() AT TIME ZONE 'Asia/Calcutta')

        console.log(query);
        // Load plots for sale layer
        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          //url: 'sql_api.php?',
          url: 'sql_api.php?',
          data: {
            api_key: api_key,
            action: 'get_data',
            query: 'where status in ("open", "Open", "OPEN")'
            },
             success:function(data) {
                //console.log(data);
                var geojson = [];       
                data.map(function (d, i) {
                    d.f_type = "plot for sale";
                    geojson.push({
                        type: "Feature",
                        geometry: {
                            type: "Point",
                            coordinates: [+d.Lon_inner, +d.Lat_inner]
                        },
                        properties: d
                    });
                });
                //console.log(geojson);
                if (map.hasLayer(sale_layer)){ map.removeLayer(sale_layer); }
                sale_geojson = { type: "FeatureCollection", features: geojson };
                //console.log(sale_geojson);
                var geojsonMarkerOptions = {
                    radius: 8,
                    fillColor: "#ff7800",
                    color: "#000",
                    weight: 1,
                    opacity: 1,
                    fillOpacity: 0.8
                };
                sale_layer = new L.GeoJSON(sale_geojson, {
                    pointToLayer: function(feature, latLng) {
                        return L.circleMarker(latLng, geojsonMarkerOptions);
                    },
                    onEachFeature : function(feature, layer){
                        //map.getZoom();
                        //console.log(feature.properties);
                        layer.bindPopup('Plot for Sale :' + feature.properties['ActualPlotNumber']);
                    }
                });
                //console.log(sale_layer);
                sale_layer.addTo(map).bringToFront();/*.on('click', function (e){
                    console.log(e)
                    var popup =  L.popup()
                        .setLatLng(e.latlng)
                        .setContent('<p>Hello world!<br />This is a nice popup.</p>')
                        .openOn(map);
                    console.log(popup);
                });*/
            }
        });
    }

    function initializemap(){   
        map = new L.Map('mapCanvas', {
            zoomControl: false,
            scrollWheelZoom: true,
            center: [16.50,80.51],
            zoom: 12,
        });
        L.control.zoom({
         position:'bottomright'
        }).addTo(map);

        basemap = L.tileLayer('http://www.google.co.in/maps/vt/lyrs=r&hl=en&x={x}&y={y}&z={z}&s=Ga', {
            detectRetina: true,
            maxNativeZoom: 25,
            maxZoom: 30,
        }).addTo(map);
        satellite = L.tileLayer('http://www.google.co.in/maps/vt/lyrs=s&hl=en&x={x}&y={y}&z={z}&s=Ga', {
            detectRetina: true,
            maxNativeZoom: 25,
            maxZoom: 30
        });         
        baseMaps = {"Basemap": basemap, "Satellite": satellite};

        var layerStyle = $('#landuse-style').text();
        cartodb.createLayer(map, {
          user_name: 'dev',
          type: 'cartodb',
          maps_api_template: 'http://{user}.cartoserver.in',
          sublayers: [{
            sql: "SELECT * FROM master",
            cartocss: layerStyle
          }]
        }).addTo(map);

        loadmap();
    }
    //----------- Map Loading functions END --------------------
```

what can be the possible error i commited

Comment: I would isolate your error, try a simple leaflet map (no Google, no Carto layer) and try to load your points and see if the pop up appears correctly or not.

Comment: i removed the carto.js and tried with leaflet.js without carto layers the error was gone. Problem was that leaflet 0.7.3 was included in carto.js and newer version leaflet.js wont work with carto.js, but now i am using carto.js beta 4.0.0 which does not include leaflet with it and i am using leaflet 1.3.1 so everything works well. cheers !!!!!!!!.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was that leaflet 0.7.3 was included in carto.js and newer version leaflet.js wont work with carto.js, but now i am using carto.js beta 4.0.0 which does not include leaflet with it and i am using leaflet 1.3.1 so everything works well. cheers !!!!!!!!.

links to both js files which work well

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.2.0/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
<script src="https://cartodb-libs.global.ssl.fastly.net/carto.js/v4.0.0-beta/carto.min.js"></script>
```

dont forget to change the carto code as per new documentation it goes like this

```
  const client = new carto.Client({
    apiKey: 'YOUR_API_KEY',
    username: 'cartojs-test'
  });

  const source = new carto.source.Dataset(`
    ne_10m_populated_places_simple
  `);
  const style = new carto.style.CartoCSS(`
    #layer {
      marker-width: 7;
      marker-fill: #EE4D5A;
      marker-line-color: #FFFFFF;
    }
  `);
  const layer = new carto.layer.Layer(source, style);

  client.addLayer(layer);
  client.getLeafletLayer().addTo(map);
```

[CARTO.js 4.0 Documentation](https://carto.com/documentation/cartojs/)

Comment: yeah, that was my impression, and why I asked you to decompose the issue :-) happy to see CARTO.js 4 (remember, still in beta status) is giving you good results

Comment: And please, mark your question as resolved so we can get it out of our radar ^_^

Comment: I have marked it solved sir, Thank you for your time sir.